# application integration with google drive

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I am working with android application integration with google drive.I want to upload .csv file of backup to google drive..But error found. my code is here..there is error after choose picture from gallery that : com.google.api.client.googleapis.extentions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthIOException

```
MainActivity.java

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Connect to Google Drive
    mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience(MainActivity.this,"852032254538-54h2nh1h5f2c4bg7ubash64d4vtcsc4f.apps.googleusercontent.com");
    startActivityForResult(mCredential.newChooseAccountIntent(),
            REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);

    mContext = MainActivity.this;

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    OnItemClickListener mMessageClickedHandler = new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position,
                long id) {
            downloadItemFromList(position);
        }
    };

    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(mMessageClickedHandler);

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            galleryIntent.setType("*/*");
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_STORE_FILE);
        }
    });

    final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mResultList = new ArrayList<File>();
                    com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Files f1 = mService
                            .files();
                    Files.List request = null;

                    do {
                        try {
                            request = f1.list();
                            request.setQ("trashed=false");
                            FileList fileList = request.execute();

                            mResultList.addAll(fileList.getItems());
                            request.setPageToken(fileList
                                    .getNextPageToken());
                        } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
                            startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(),
                                    REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            if (request != null) {
                                request.setPageToken(null);
                            }
                        }
                    } while (request.getPageToken() != null
                            && request.getPageToken().length() > 0);

                    populateListView();
                }
            });
            t.start();

        }
    });
}

private void downloadItemFromList(int position) {
    mDLVal = (String) mListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
    showToast("You just pressed: " + mDLVal);

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (File tmp : mResultList) {
                if (tmp.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(mDLVal)) {
                    if (tmp.getDownloadUrl() != null
                            && tmp.getDownloadUrl().length() > 0) {
                        try {
                            com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse resp = mService
                                    .getRequestFactory()
                                    .buildGetRequest(
                                            new GenericUrl(tmp
                                                    .getDownloadUrl()))
                                    .execute();
                            InputStream iStream = resp.getContent();
                            try {
                                final java.io.File file = new java.io.File(
                                        Environment
                                                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                                        Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
                                                .getPath(), tmp.getTitle());
                                showToast("Downloading: "
                                        + tmp.getTitle()
                                        + " to "
                                        + Environment
                                                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                                        Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
                                                .getPath());
                                storeFile(file, iStream);
                            } finally {
                                iStream.close();
                            }

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
}

private void populateListView() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mFileArray = new String[mResultList.size()];
            int i = 0;
            for (File tmp : mResultList) {
                mFileArray[i] = tmp.getTitle();
                i++;
            }
            mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mFileArray);
            mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
    });
}

private void storeFile(java.io.File file, InputStream iStream) {
    try {
        final OutputStream oStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        try {
            try {
                final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int read;
                while ((read = iStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    oStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
                oStream.flush();
            } finally {
                oStream.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode,
        final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null
                && data.getExtras() != null) {
            String accountName = data
                    .getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
            if (accountName != null) {
                mCredential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
                mService = getDriveService(mCredential);
            }
        }
        break;
    case REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // account already picked
        } else {
            startActivityForResult(mCredential.newChooseAccountIntent(),
                    REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
        }
        break;
    case RESULT_STORE_FILE:
        mFileUri = data.getData();
        // Save the file to Google Drive
        saveFileToDrive();
        break;
    }
}

private Drive getDriveService(GoogleAccountCredential credential) {
    return new Drive.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
            new GsonFactory(), credential).build();
}

private void saveFileToDrive() {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // Create URI from real path
                String path;
                path = getPathFromUri(mFileUri);
                mFileUri = Uri.fromFile(new java.io.File(path));

                ContentResolver cR = MainActivity.this.getContentResolver();
                Log.d("tag123", "go to save in drive");
                // File's binary content
                java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(mFileUri
                        .getPath());
                Log.d("tag123", "get path from resourse");
                FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(cR
                        .getType(mFileUri), fileContent);
                Log.d("tag123", "selected");
                showToast("Selected " + mFileUri.getPath() + "to upload");

                // File's meta data.
                File body = new File();
                body.setTitle(fileContent.getName());
                body.setMimeType(cR.getType(mFileUri));
                Log.d("tag123", "store in other file");

                com.google.api.services.drive.model.File file = mService
                        .files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();

                if (file != null) {
                    showToast("Uploaded: " + file.getTitle());
                }
            } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
                startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                showToast("Transfer ERROR: " + e.toString());
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
}

public void showToast(final String toast) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toast,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

public String getPathFromUri(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null,
            null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Comment: Can you add the error code you encountered?

Comment: I found solution only problem is that version of play service lib

Comment: Now working on download from drive..

Comment: Good hear! Don't mention it, though I really didn't do anything helpful XD. Just update your post if there is an issued encoutered if it is still related to your original post, if not create a new question.

Comment: I am trying on download from drive..if any issue found then sure update..